# IE10 SVG implementation refusing to antialias <rect> elements?

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-10, antialiasing

I've been working on a charting library using d3 and SVG to display a series of rectangles. The dataset governs the number of rectangles to be displayed in a given area, and in most cases, the math doesn't work out cleanly, meaning the rectangles don't start and end on whole numbers. Firefox, Chrome and Safari all address this contingency by antialiasing the rectangles. IE seems to just round to the nearest pixel value, and refuses to antialias any rect elements. I've tried changing shape-rendering and the like, to no avail.

Here's a side-by-side comparison of the same data in IE10 and the most recent Chrome release:

IE10:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Is anyone aware of a fix for this that doesn't involve changing the structure of the SVG markup? Setting CSS properties or tag attributes is preferable to changing the elements themselves. Barring that, has anyone seen any Microsoft documentation explaining the rationale for this decision? I haven't been able to turn up any thus far.

Comment: Your images look exactly the same.

Comment: They're showing the same data, but one is rendered in Chrome and the other in IE10. All of the bars in the Chrome rendering should look evenly thick and evenly spaced, and have antialiased edges. The ones in the IE rendering should have sharp edges with no partial transparency, the columns are spaced unevenly, and the fourth column from the right is only half the thickness of the others.

If, knowing that, they _still_ look exactly the same, then something _really_ weird is going on...

Comment: oh right, now I see. Anti-aliasing behavior is not specified and so these decisions are very platform/browser specific and happen at the level of the underlying native graphics library (which can also product different results depending on GPU vs. CPU rendering).   Usually using crispEdges will get you the non-anti-aliased result on every platform. You can sometimes "hand-anti-alias" by adding a filter, but results are not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't seem to care about the shape-rendering property, but I've found that you can force it to anti-alias shapes by specifying a tiny rotate transformation:

```
svg {
    transform: rotate(.00001deg); /* hack to force anti-aliasing in IE */
}
```

Tested on IE11.